# Why do I get the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in swift

Tags: swift, fatal-error

I am only two weeks into swift so my code will be very basic and not perfect I am trying to solve this problem "Create a function that returns the minimum number of removals to make the sum of all elements in an array even."
like this
minimumRemovals([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ➞ 1

```
minimumRemovals([5, 7, 9, 11]) ➞ 0

minimumRemovals([5, 7, 9, 12]) ➞ 1
```

but I keep get the error  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Here is my code

'''

```
func minimumRemovals( arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    var odds = 0
    var evens = 0
    for i in arr {
        if arr[i] % 2 == 0 {
            evens += 1
        } else {
            odds += 1
        }
    }
    if odds == evens {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
print(minimumRemovals(arr: [1,2,3,4,5]))
'''
```

Comment: `for i in arr` iterates over the array *elements,* not over the array indices.

Comment: Add `print(i)` to your loop and you'll see the problem. (Is *debugging* deprecated nowadays?)

Comment: Btw, the logic of you program is wrong. The sum of [1,2,3,4] is even, but your function (if fixed) would return 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for .. in ..` in Swift does not iterate over indices. It iterates over actual array elements. Hence `i` is the element, not the index.

Using `if i % 2 == 0` will fix your problem.

Comment: That will fix the crash, but will not produce the expected output.

Comment: The Q is for fixing the crash. Solving the algorithm is a different problem. Which is best left for the OP.

Comment: Leaving the loop body empty would fix it as well :) – OP apparently needs to inspect the parity of the array *elements.*